# How to position krank Tooltips the same in different browsers?

Tags: css, woocommerce, cross-browser, media-queries, css-position

I've positioned 3 tooltip text elements using CSS `position:relative`, `top` and `left` with pixels next to dropdown menus. The text shown is called "What is This?".

The only problem is every browser and device displays the drop downs differently, throwing off my positioning. Is there a better way to position them so I don't have write a different rule for every device and browser?

```
button.krank-tooltip.ttone {position: relative;top: 73px;right: -280px;} 
button.krank-tooltip.tttwo {position: relative;top: 114px;right: -168px;} 
button.krank-tooltip.ttthree {position: relative;top: 154px;right: -108px;}
```

#### Here is what it looks like on a mac with Google:

[image: on a mac with Google] (http://gyazo.com/f67d52f2e6db4cc9488247f5877f79e1)

#### and here is Windows 8.1 with Google:

[image: on windows with Google]
(http://gyazo.com/4577e66867ecb180ba293f2ca504c10b)

It looks correct on the mac but is off slightly on the PC.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Hi Thanks,

`button.krank-tooltip.ttone {position: relative;top: 73px;right: -280px;}

button.krank-tooltip.tttwo {position: relative;top: 114px;right: -168px;}

button.krank-tooltip.ttthree {position: relative;top: 154px;right: -108px;}`

Sending a screenshot

Comment: Here is what it looks like on a mac with Google: https://gyazo.com/f67d52f2e6db4cc9488247f5877f79e1

Windows 8.1 Google: https://gyazo.com/4577e66867ecb180ba293f2ca504c10b

Comment: stybl, Is above code what you wanted to see?

Comment: I'm new, can someone please give me a hand as to how I should write this question so It doesn't get put on hold?

Comment: Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and follow the guidelines there to post your question again, this time with the relevant code in the question body.

Comment: I've had a go at updating the question for you. Hope it helps. The main change I've made is so people don't have to look elsewhere to get the information to help you (ie info in links offsite, comments). Editing the original question will get more positive attention.